# EF7 Reverse Engineer Existing DB - Timeout error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am executing the following command (executing this inside the asp.net 5 project folder using cmd)

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=SQL2K14;Initial Catalog=movies;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;password=pass" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer --outputDir Models
```

and get the following error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.) period has expired.)

I know for a fact there is nothing wrong with my connection string because i use the same exact connecting string from the same exact machine (inside the asp.net project) using `SqlCommand` to open the connection and retrieve stuff.  So this would not be a network related issue or connection string at all, its purely to do with the `dnx ef dbcontext` command

According to http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet5/existing-db.html#reverse-engineer-your-model this is the way to reverse engineer it but I am not sure if they updated it to be done another way as this suggests its complex and it will be simplified but not sure when it will be

Answer (score 1):

My commandline which works for comparism is (note connection string format is different)

`dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer --context ReportingDbContext --output-dir Models`

Run from the root of my project directory

Comment: is there no username and password required?

Comment: is your db on the same machine?

Comment: this indeed worked for me too on a remote server with a password protected database - but I have to check on the latter